# Listen to TCP traffic and trigger an event

Tags: iis-7, haproxy

Is there any software available that will listen for TCP packets and execute some event or (code, script, exe, etc) when packets matching a specific filter are detected?

To give you an example of what I'm trying to do. Say I have 2 web servers, one development and one for production. I want to be able to push a code update to my development server and replicate all of the requests hitting my production server onto the development server to test stress and concurrency.

There are other applications I've found that are very close to what I need but they lack one very important thing, Real-Time execution. I cannot record the TCP traffic then replay it at a later time, it needs to be done in real time.

Current setup (ii7 with haproxy)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what an [intrusion detection system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) does.  An IDS is normally used for security purposes -- that is, to detect and respond to network-based attacks -- but I'm sure something like [snort](http://snort.org) could be made to do what you want.

That said, I don't think this is actually the right tool for the job.  Maybe a better solution would be to watch your access log and replay the requests on your development host.

Comment: Interesting product I'll have to give it a look. I also found some HTTP Modules you can make for IIS7 that intercepts logs real time before they're written to disk. Problem is that I haven't found any that specifically do what I would need so I have to take time to create my own module, but that's also a solution I suppose.